# Septic system was designed for 3 bedrooms but we need 4, what are my options?

Tags: septic

We're looking to build an in-law  space and for it to be legal it has to have a bedroom, which means our septic is undersized. The town has our house listed as three bedrooms (*It's actually already four bedroom house*) even though the tank is 1500G. I guess it has something to do with how fast the water drains?

We'd prefer not to have to replace the septic as that would increase the cost but I'm confused as too why our system can not handle it if our tank is already 1500 gallons.

Could we possibly just upgrade some components to give us that expansion?

We have the original design docs, what should I look for to answer this question?

Comment: This cannot be answered generally.  You'll need to check with your local AHJ and find out what the local code says regarding septic capacity.  Chances are, however, that you're going to be stuck with a major septic installation as almost nobody oversizes a septic system on initial install.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but this is just how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your maths... You say you want to go from 3 beds to 4 but then say it's already four... So what you really mean (but missed in the addition) is that you want to go from 4 to 5, or actually you are currently rated for 3 and will be getting rated for 5.

Comment: Realistically, are the regulations based on expected occupancy? One could use that reference for how well the system can handle the additional bodies.

Comment: This may be simple if there is enough property and or good drainage the tank is not your limiting factor your field is most likely based on x number of feet of field per bedroom.

Answer (score 2):

There are a combination of rules for septic systems.

The size of the tank is one of the things but it is not the most important.

The drain field has more to do with the size of the system and the percolating rate or how rapidly the water from the field leaches into the ground(or not).

I have built homes where 75’ was enough for each bedroom and others took almost 200’ per bedroom (heavy clay but the soil met the minimum percolating rate) both had the same size 2 chamber tanks.

It may be as easy if you have enough property to add a distribution box on one of your existing lines in the field and create a larger field.

Check with your local building codes office (where you get the permits) they may say on an existing system no problem or if the area ok known for problems or close to a stream , creek or listed county drainage area it may not be possible.

I have turned 2 bedroom homes into 4 bedroom with this simple (but kind of yukky) addition to the existing field. I have also been told no it would require a pumped / mound system (very expensive) and they did not even really look at the lot map they also did not get the permits and extra taxes for the improvements oh well.

So it may be possible and not that difficult check with your county offices and maybe it will only be 100’ of lines (put in 200 so your home would be legal).